# sum array javascript give me error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sum

i have an array that contains numbers, with a function and a for cycle i sum all the numbers inside it:

```
$scope.selectedVoicesCss = []; //The array with numbers
$scope.TotaleCss = 0; // return me the sum of numbers

//this function populate the array 
$scope.AggiornaTotaleCss = function(param,costo,index) {
    if(costo){
        $scope.selectedVoicesCss.push(param);
        AggiornaCss();
    } else{
        $scope.selectedVoicesCss.splice(index,1);           
    }
}

//This function is for loop 
function AggiornaCss(){
    alert($scope.selectedVoicesCss); //it return me correct data!
    for(var i = 0, n=$scope.selectedVoicesCss.length; i<n; i++) {
        $scope.TotaleCss +=selectedVoicesCss[i];
    }       
}
```

It seems ok, so why console return me this error?:
**Error: selectedVoicesCss is not defined**

Comment: `$scope.TotaleCss += $scope.selectedVoicesCss[i];` instead of `$scope.TotaleCss +=selectedVoicesCss[i];`. you should've looked more carefully at the error though, it's self-explanatory whatsoever ;)

Comment: whoa! you are right :D

Answer (score 1):

In this `$scope.TotaleCss +=selectedVoicesCss[i];` line you are missing `$scope`,

Change it to

```
 $scope.TotaleCss +=$scope.selectedVoicesCss[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change
`$scope.TotaleCss +=selectedVoicesCss[i];`
to
`$scope.TotaleCss += $scope.selectedVoicesCss[i];`

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.selectedVoicesCss != selectedVoicesCss
```

so just use

```
$scope.selectedVoicesCss
```

Comment: @Rajesh thanks for edit answering from mobile is a pain in ass :D

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$scope.TotaleCss +=selectedVoicesCss[i];` use `$scope.TotaleCss += $scope.selectedVoicesCss[i];`. You've missed `$scope`.